# Laravel route in bootstrap button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I want to make a button that links to route: normindex

This blow does not seem to work.

```
 <button href={{ HTML::link('normindex')}} type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
 <button href="normindex" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
```

This below does work but generates a link, not a button.

`{{ HTML::link('normindex','Left')}}`

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, they don't work because `HTML::link()` will output a full HTML link, while your second attempt just uses plain text in the `href` attribute, so there is no way for Laravel to know that it needs to include something in there.

---

You can try this:

```
 <button href="{{ route('normindex') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
```

The [`route()`](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls) helper will print the URL of the route that you pass to it. This will need a named route in your `routes.php` file, such as:

```
Route::get('your-path', array('as' => 'normindex', function()
{
   // do stuff
}));
```

Comment: your-path could this be Normcontroller@index. Bause the full route i am using is: Route::get('normindex', 'Normcontroller@index');

Comment: `your-path` should be the value that you use to access that route in your browser. In my example: `http://example.com/your-path`

Comment: If you write the ``href`` attribute on the ``button``, it will not work.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('normindex') }}" class="btn btn-default"> Norm Index </a>
```

**or**

```
link_to_route('normindex', 'Norm Index', null, array('class' => 'btn btn-default'));
```

Comment: "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "normindex" as such route does not exist."
Strange thing is it does exist:
Route::get('normindex', 'Normcontroller@index');

Comment: That should be Route::get('normindex', array('as' => 'normindex', 'uses' => 'Normcontroller@index') );

Answer (score 2):

Shanaka's solution worked, but the single quote defining the class is in the wrong place and it's missing a close parenthesis.

Correction:

```
{!! Html::linkRoute('posts.show','cancel',array($post->id),array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block')) !!}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out, once you have enough rep you can even write comments, which are more appropriate for little corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Add a **button class** from bootstrap to your route

```
{!! Html::linkRoute('posts.show','cancel',array($post->id),array('class=>'btn btn-danger btn-block')!!}
```

Comment: [blahblahber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7649421/blahblahber) claimed that this should be correct instead: `{!! Html::linkRoute('posts.show','cancel',array($post->id),array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block')) !!}`

Comment: Their corrections contain a single quote after class and another closing paren.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `<a>` tag with bootstrap btn class:

`<a class="btn btn-default"  href="{{ route('normindex') }}">Left</a>`